# Google Cloud Vision API on emulator works 6x faster rather than on real device

Tags: android, google-vision

I am in process of integration Google Cloud Vision API to my app.
I noticed that Text Detection, Label Detection works on real device 6x slower rather than on Android emulator.

The reason of issue is NOT low internet speed in real device. Because another app part, which also makes http request, gives one performance for real device and emulator.

The issue is reproducible at official Google [Cloud Vision Android Sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android)

Tested on 2 different real devices and 2 emulators.

Any ideas why it happens?

**Code from official sample:**

```
private void callCloudVision(final Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    // Switch text to loading
    mImageDetails.setText(R.string.loading_message);

    // Do the real work in an async task, because we need to use the network anyway
    new AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
                JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

                Vision.Builder builder = new Vision.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
                builder.setVisionRequestInitializer(new
                        VisionRequestInitializer(CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY));
                Vision vision = builder.build();

                BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchAnnotateImagesRequest =
                        new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
                batchAnnotateImagesRequest.setRequests(new ArrayList<AnnotateImageRequest>() {{
                    AnnotateImageRequest annotateImageRequest = new AnnotateImageRequest();

                    //https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages
                    ImageContext imageContext = new ImageContext();
                    List<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
                    languages.add("pl");
                    imageContext.setLanguageHints(languages);
                    annotateImageRequest.setImageContext(imageContext);

                    // Add the image
                    Image base64EncodedImage = new Image();
                    // Convert the bitmap to a JPEG
                    // Just in case it's a format that Android understands but Cloud Vision
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    // Base64 encode the JPEG
                    base64EncodedImage.encodeContent(imageBytes);
                    annotateImageRequest.setImage(base64EncodedImage);

                    // add the features we want
                    annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(new ArrayList<Feature>() {{
                        Feature labelDetection = new Feature();
                        labelDetection.setType("LABEL_DETECTION");
                        labelDetection.setMaxResults(10);
                        add(labelDetection);
                    }});

                    // Add the list of one thing to the request
                    add(annotateImageRequest);
                }});

                Vision.Images.Annotate annotateRequest =
                        vision.images().annotate(batchAnnotateImagesRequest);
                // Due to a bug: requests to Vision API containing large images fail when GZipped.
                annotateRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "created Cloud Vision request object, sending request");

                BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = annotateRequest.execute();
                return convertResponseToString(response);

            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to make API request because " + e.getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to make API request because of other IOException " +
                        e.getMessage());
            }
            return "Cloud Vision API request failed. Check logs for details.";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mImageDetails.setText(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Time results for processing one image after 3 tests: 
**real device**
48409608471
49837573418
48430621961

**emulator**
7725682517
7967006977
5478519794

I used simple

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long duration = (endTime - startTime);
```

Comment: Because ARM processors have much lower absolute performance than x86?  OCR is a high processing power activity.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, OCR is server task. Does processors power really matters in this case?

Comment: OCR is very rarely a server task.  Its almost always done on the client.  That's why libraries like tesseract are so big and written in C-  if you were doing it on the server they would be simple http requests.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan in my case it is Server task. I use http request to OCR server. One (my own) server uses Tesseract, another one  (Google) uses Vision API. But may be building Bitmap etc is very expensive task...

Comment: I suggest you remove mention to tesseract and mention you're making a server request for the OCR data to your question.  Otherwise its confusing.  I also suggest timing how long it takes to put the request together, how long the network request takes, and (server side) how long processing the request takes for both modes to narrow down the problem.

Comment: How does this relate to google-app-engine?